# Issue with User Role Resources Tree

Tags: magento2, user-roles, admin-user

I have to get helped in some parts of my website with a friend who is a developer, so he asked me the access to the backend.

Being that I don't want to give the full access, I have created a new user and a new role just for him.

When I started to customize the resources, I have selected everything without the `Permissions > User` section.

And then came the issue: opening the backend with the new user, I don't see some sections. They just disappeared.

Going back to the resources tree, I discovered that they never been there, so I can't select the sections. But if I select Resource access > All, the sections are shown again in the left backend panel.

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
These are some pics, as you can see if the admin has full roles I can see the Porto Icon (in this example)

[image: Pic 1]

But if I manage admin roles, putting custom and deflagging in that case the User permissions

[image: Pic 2]

I lose the Porto icon section, as you can see.

[image: Pic 3]

I think that probably it happens because when I choose "Select all" Magento selects all the sections - even the ones that I can't see in the Role Resources tree, so if I put "Custom" I am not able to select everything because I don't see some sections.

Comment: can you post a screenshot or 2? I don't really understand what's happening

Comment: Are the missing resources related to some custom module or Magento's core module? If the resources are from custom module, then there may be problem in defining **acl** for the module.

Comment: ok, added some pics. Thanks everyone for the reply and let me know if now you understand better the question, thank you!

Comment: @MohitKumarArora sorry I read only now. Yes the resources are from custom module, how do I define acl?

Comment: Any solution for this?